# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help I am trying to execute the following stored procedure. I receive an error message stating that Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bpc2016.entity' in 'field list'. The error disappears when I take out the reference to industryPY in the industryCY view. Please help the table and column exist in the database.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAbudgetnow`()
BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW industryPY
AS
SELECT
alet.area AS 'area',
alet.industry_description AS 'industry_desc',
alet.industry AS 'industry',
alet.percentage AS 'perc',
ref_data.product AS 'product',
ref_data.pz AS 'pz',
ref_data.rate AS 'amount'
FROM
alet
RIGHT JOIN
ref_data ON (alet.industry = ref_data.industry and alet.area = ref_data.area)
WHERE alet.industry IS NOT NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW industryCY
AS
SELECT
bpc2016.entity AS 'entity',
bpc2016.plant AS 'plant',
bpc2016.product_desc AS 'product_desc',
bpc2016.product AS 'product',
bpc2016.customer AS 'customer',
bpc2016.route AS 'route',
bpc2016.pz_desc AS 'pz_desc',
bpc2016.pz AS 'pz',
bpc2016.amount AS 'amount',
industryPY.area AS 'area',
industryPY.industry_desc AS 'industry_desc',
industryPY.industry AS 'industry',
industryPY.perc AS 'percentage',
industryPY.amount AS 'PYamount',
TRUNCATE(bpc2016.amount*industryPY.perc,2) AS 'budget_2016_vol'
FROM
bpc2016
FULL JOIN
industryPY ON (bpc2016.pz = industryPY.pz and bpc2016.product = industryPY.product);

END
```

[image]

'bpc2016', (\n
`entity` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`plant` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`product_desc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`product` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`interplant` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`customer` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`route` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`pz_desc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`pz` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',\n
`amount` float NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Comment: error message is clear - it cant reference the field `bpc2016.entity`. you should post the create table statement for `bpc2016`

Comment: the bpc 2016 table already exists in the db with data

Comment: @the_big_blackbox : but it seems there is no entity field in it... Show table definition.

Comment: Also mysql doesnt have FULL JOIN al least not directly

Comment: hi guys, table definition included

Answer (score 0):

You may redefine the delimiter in order to tell the parser where in your procedure the statements end;

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAbudgetnow`()
BEGIN

  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW industryPY 
  AS
  SELECT
  alet.area AS 'area',
  alet.industry_description AS 'industry_desc',
  alet.industry AS 'industry',
  alet.percentage AS 'perc',
  ref_data.product AS 'product',
  ref_data.pz AS 'pz',
  ref_data.rate AS 'amount'
  FROM
  alet
  RIGHT JOIN
  ref_data ON (alet.industry = ref_data.industry and alet.area = ref_data.area)
  WHERE alet.industry IS NOT NULL;

  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW industryCY
  AS
  ...
  ;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help this seems to be the problem - Mihai was right  "mysql doesnt have `FULL JOIN` al least not directly" when i substitute the full join for a `right` or `left join` the procedure executes.